# Is there a library to see the weights being learned by RASA NLU interpreter after training?

Tags: nlp, rasa-nlu, named-entity-extraction

I'm using RASA NLU for entity extraction from healthcare invoices. I have manually tagged and trained OCR extracted data from these invoices with 10 relevant entities(Clinic name, clinic address...). RASA implicitly learns several features from the data. Is there any way to see these features and weights being learned for these features?

I have already tried [ELI5](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) but it doesn't support rasa interpreter it seems.

Has anyone come across this? Thanks in advance

Comment: which NLU pipeline are you using?

Comment: i was using various pipelines and experimenting. Since I was new to NLP, I thought that RASA was the only way for CRF. Now I am able to see the weights learned using sklearn's CRF

Comment: ok, so this question is resolved? Maybe you could explain a bit how you did it :-)